# Remove Foreign Key constraint error in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

**Hello Guys**, Hope you are doing well. I am working on my **spring boot** project where I add two entities ***Category*** and ***Item*** and the relationship between them is ***OneToMany*** i.e. One **Category** can have multiple **items** and many items can have only one **category**.
According to my project requirement When the user deletes the **category** then its associate **items** will also be deleted. But when I try to delete the **category** it says;

```
    Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`srms_db`.`issued_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK64cj06b00l58h8yi4msjuljll` FOREIGN KEY (`ii_fk`) REFERENCES `item` (`item_id`))
```

I am giving some code for more explanation;

**Category Entity Code**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cat_id", nullable = false)
    private int catId;

    @Column(name = "cat_type", nullable = false)
    private String catType;

    @Column(name = "cat_desc", nullable = true)
    private String catDesc;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Items> items;
```

*And the*

**Item Entity Code**

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Items implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "item_id")
    private int itemId;

    @Column(name = "item_name", nullable = false)
    private String itemName;

    @Column(name = "item_quantity", nullable = false)
    private int itemQuantity;

    @Column(name = "item_received_date", nullable = false)
    private Date itemReceivedDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<DamageItem> damageItems;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<IssuedItem> issuedItems;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ic_fk")
    private Category category;
}
```

**Note**
*`I also try on cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, DETACH, REFRESH, etc but futile`*

**Issued Item Entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Issued_Item")
public class IssuedItem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "issued_id", nullable = false)
    private int IssuedItemId;

    @Column(name = "issued_from", nullable = false)
    private String IssuedFrom;

    @Column(name = "issued_to", nullable = false)
    private String IssuedTo;

    @Column(name = "issued_quantity", nullable = false)
    private int IssuedQuantity;

    @Column(name = "issued_date", nullable = false)
    private Date IssuedDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ii_fk")
    private Items item;
}
```

I am also providing the ***damage Item Entity*** code

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Damage_Item")
public class DamageItem implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "damage_id", nullable = false)
    private int DamageItemId;

    @Column(name = "damage_quantity", nullable = false)
    private int DamageQuantity;

    @Column(name = "damage_date", nullable = false)
    private Date DamageDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_fk")
    private Items item;
}
```

**Thanks In Advance.**

Comment: I'd like to see the JPA/Hibernate imports on `Category` class.

Comment: some of my import are; `package com.srms.Models;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;`

Comment: How are you deleting the Category ?

Comment: By SQL query `DELETE FROM Category WHERE cat_id=1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally**, I solved the problem, I think the spring boot can't explicitly set the constraint you have to manually set the **OnUpdate** and **OnDelete** to **Cascade** or something according to your need.

I use the Sqlyoq to change that setting the below *screenshot* will clear the idea

[image]

As you see I set the **OnUpdate** and **OnDelete** to **Cascade**. Thanks For help :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are generating your DB schema not using JPA (Hibernate or Spring Data). So perhaps the constraint is being generated in DB level without cascade option.

More info:

Regarding to the following documentation you can let the application create the schema:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

> JPA has features for DDL generation, and these can be set up to run on startup against the database. This is controlled through two external properties:
>
> spring.jpa.generate-ddl (boolean) switches the feature on and off and is vendor independent.
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto (enum) is a Hibernate feature that controls the behavior in a more fine-grained way. This feature is described in more detail later in this guide.

Comment: But I properly set the database connection i.e.               
`spring.datasource.name = srmsDS
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/srms_db
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true`

Comment: Change the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` value only once to `create-drop` value and let your schema be deleted and created again. (Caution: you will lose all data)

Comment: I deleted and created so many times but when I perform delete operation, it gives the foreign key constraints error.

Comment: Look at your DB FK constraint DDL after it has been created and look if it has `ON DELETE CASCADE` or not.

`FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: Where can I find it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_descc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4                  
 Here is my Category Table DDL